# How to import and use bootstrap-vue with Webpack

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I started a project using [vuejs-templates and webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack#usage).

Then I added [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.github.io/) to the project.

Now, I am not sure how to add a bootstrap button.

In `main.js` I am importing `BootstrapVue`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import App from './App'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

However, I when I try and use the `<b-button>` element in `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <b-button :size="size" :variant="variant" @click="clicked">
      Click Me!
    </b-button>
    <hello></hello>
  </div>
</template>
```

Errors are thrown about all the property attributes associated with the `<b-button>` element.

How do I use this?

Comment: Have you noticed that the `size` and `variant` use a local variable to determine the value?  you can use a direct string just to test that it works. remove the : before them and type a string in the attribute

Comment: I'd also check which version of the Vue runtime you have, if it's the compile only runtime you can't use `template` you have to use a render function.
You can try:
`render: function(createElement) { return createElement(App); }`

Comment: thx to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

You should define at your app Vue instance following:

```
data:{
    size: 0, //needed size 
    variant: 'success' // needed variant
},
methods:{
    clicked(){
        console.log('im clicked')
    }
}
```